# ¿Cómo guardo valores enteros en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

tengo un programa que pide al usuario una lista de números separados por comas, luego debo guardar esos números en una lista, mi código es el siguiente;

```
numbers1 = input("Introduzca números separados por comas: ")

list1 = []

def create_list_numbers(list , numbers_string):

i = 0
number = 0

while i < len(numbers_string):

    if numbers_string[i].isnumeric() :

        number = number + (int(numbers_string[i]))
        i += 1
    else:
        list.append(numbers_string[i])
        number = 0
        i += 1


create_list_numbers(list1 , numbers1)
print(list1)
```

Comment: Bienvenido CerberusVT a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Puedes convertir una cadena directamente a una lista, por ej: `"1,2,3".split(',')`